# Python Web-scraping - Nested Tags

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get information from the page below

```
http://books.toscrape.com/
```

I want to get the rating (stars) of each book and I used the code below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

response = requests.get(
    'http://books.toscrape.com/')
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Requisição bem sucedida!')

linhas = soup.find_all(class_=re.compile("rating"))
```

but what comes is the following

```
<p class="star-rating Three">
<i class="icon-star"></i>
<i class="icon-star"></i>
<i class="icon-star"></i>
<i class="icon-star"></i>
<i class="icon-star"></i>
</p>,
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `soup.find_all("p",class_="star-rating")` will work

Comment: thanks for the help but still the same

Comment: @RicardoCauduro Can you edit your question and rewrite it in english? Or post here: `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/`

Comment: sorry....translated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually class-name is contain the star value so we can extract using `attrs['class']` mehtod or `d['class'][1]` also works!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

response = requests.get(
    'http://books.toscrape.com/')

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")

data=soup.find_all("p",class_="star-rating")
for d in data:
    print(d.attrs['class'][1])
```

Output:

```
Three
One
One
Four
..
```